# Binding a keystroke in visual studio 2008, programming in c#

Tags: c#

Still a programming noob but I'm getting better.

Right now I am programming a simon says game. There are four buttons. My code works perfect in terms of functionality. However, instead of clicking on the button I want to bind keystrokes to it. I've seen many confusing methods and some rather simple. However, I have yet to find a keybinding solution for visual studio 2008. So basically, when the program is running, if I press the 'A' button, then I want my program to act like the red button was just clicked. Thank you!

Comment: Two things, visual studio is a development environment so it won't effect your solution. Second don't worry about binding the key to the button, just have your button click and a button point to the same method, look up handling windows messages for keypresses

Comment: Watch one of the keyboard events.  Attempt somethng and update your question with your attempt.

Comment: OP, I've noticed you've asked a few questions but still haven't accepted any answers. If you feel an answer provided to your question has resolved your issue, please click the check mark next to the response to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to listen to a keystroke event on your form.  To do this, select your form in the visual studio designer and go to the properties panel.  Click the lightning bolt (events) icon and double clikc on the `KeyDown` event.

[image: Event Properties]

This will generate the following code

```c#
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

This will fire whenever a key is pressed down.  Next, you want to check which key was clicked and handle appropriately

Inside of your the **`KeyDown` method**, add the following code:

```c#
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
{
    //Do stuff when 'A' Key is pressed
}
```

Also, consider adding a **`switch`** statement if you're trying to listen to multiple keys and determine the action based on that, for example:

```c#
switch (e.KeyCode ) {
    case Keys.A:
        //Preform Code for A
        break;
    case Keys.W:
        //Preform Code for W
        break;
    //You can add as many case statments as you like...
}
```

You'll have to make sure that **`KeyPreview`** is set to true so that keyboard events properly register with the form.  This can be done during initialization or on the form properties panel.

[image: Set KeyPreview to True]

To call the same code is pretty straight forward.  You can either have the red button `Click` event call into the same method as the keystroke event.  If you really wanted, you could leave the logic in the button click event and just call that method and pass nulls as arguments

For example, you could do the following:

```c#
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        RedButton_Click(null, null);
    }
}

private void RedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do red button stuffs
}
```

Comment: Am I supposed to initialize KeyCode somehow? That's the only difference between your code and mine, my "KeyCode" is not lighting up. If I do need to initialize it, what kinda of datatype is it? What I mean is, where is KeyCode coming from? Thank you!

Comment: No wait, I got it. Your directions worked out perfectly. Thank you! Much love coming from a fledgling programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event.

```
yourControl.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(control_KeyDown);

static void control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        //The 'A' key has been pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnkeyPress` event of your `Form`:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyChar == 'A')
              //your code
}
```

Write this code simply in your `form` code.